# How to get the file from multiple file upload using ajax with python django?

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I have a project that requires uploading of documents. I don't know why the files turns empty when submitting in AJAX going to my views in Django.

Here's my code:

Template

```
<div>
    <input type="file" name="userfile" id="userfile" multiple/><br/>
    <span class="btn btn-default btn-xs" onclick="btnUpload();">Upload</span>
</div>
```

AJAX

```
var form_data = new FormData();
form_data.append('userfile', $('input[type="file"]')[0].files)
form_data.append('csrfmiddlewaretoken', $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val());
$.ajax({
    url:"/onlinerpta/register_doc/",
    data:form_data,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    type:'POST',
    success: function(msg){
        bootbox.alert(msg.feedback);
    }
});
```

Views

```
for userfiledata in request.FILES.getlist('userfile'):
    f = userfiledata.FILES['userfile']
    print (f)
```

It returns `f=''` on my output.

Comment: You don't need to again filter the **userfiledata**. Please try to print the **userfiledata** itself and check what it is showing.

Comment: it print []. does it mean I have error in ajax?

Comment: It seems like you are getting an empty list instead of the uploaded files. please print this too: `request.FILES.getlist('userfile')`